# Youtube API v3 Error: 403 (playlistItemsNotAccessible)

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

This is my first post at stackoverflow - please let me know if I should rephrase the question and/or provide more details regarding the issue.

Using the javascript examples provided on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#create_a_playlist we have successfully been able to create youtube playlists and also update them with new videos. However, trying to add videos to a playlist created by another user generates the following error.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.playlistItem",
    "reason": "playlistItemsNotAccessible",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

In Youtube we have granted permissions for the other user to add videos in the particular playlist and that user has clicked the "contribution acception link".

(If Youtube Direct Lite wouldn't throw API v2-errors when trying to view pending additions, we would have been using that app.)

Comment: The user whos playlist you are trying to add to must have authenticate your application.  You cant update someone else's playlist without there permission.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you mean the "oAuth consent screen"? If so this has been done by the other user. Sorry for not making this clear in the original post.

Comment: If the consent screen was authenticate by another user then the only user whos play list you can update is this other user.     I run your application i give you permissions to access my playlists.   John does not run your application and give you permission to access his play list you cant update his play list.   (Get the idea?)

Comment: Does it make any difference if you Tick the box that says "Allow people with the link to add videos" - https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6109639?hl=en-GB

Comment: Joe: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunatly no, we tried that.

DalmTo: We do get the concept that you can't just go around adding videos to random peoples playlists. We still don't really understand how to set permissions to allow "user X" adding videos to "my playlist" via the API.

Comparing our solution with Youtube Direct Lite we can't really see the difference, In YDL "user X" is able to add videos to "my playlist". However YDL-admin does not seem to be able to list pending approvals anymore, but that is another issue: https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/issues/detail?id=51

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these scopes for your projects in Google Cloud Platform.

1. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner
2. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
3. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl

**Link to your project**

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent/edit?project=HERE_IS_YOUR_PROJECT_ID

**Step 1**
Click to `EDIT APP`

[image]

**Step 2** Scroll down and click `SAVE AND CONTINUE`

[image]

**Step 3** Click to `ADD OR REMOVE SCOPES`

[image]

**Step 4** Select these scopes

[image]

**Step 5** Scroll down and click `UPDATE`

[image]

**Step 6** Now You will see these added scopes

[image]

**Step 7** Scroll down and click `SAVE AND CONTINUE`

[image]

And do not forget to add scopes in your code.

Here is an Android code example.

```
private static final String[] SCOPES = {YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_READONLY, YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_FORCE_SSL, YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE, YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBEPARTNER};
```